# How to Windows authenticate to SQL Server with pyodbc

Tags: python, pyodbc

I can successfully connect to database with SQL Management Studio with Authentication "Windows Authentication" or "Azure Active Directory - Universal with MFA".

I can successfully connect with database with Python code with SQL authentication:

```
import pyodbc 

conndev = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
                  'Server=server124.database.windows.net,1433;'
                  'Database=db345;'
                  'UID=username;'
                  'PWD=password;'
                  'Trusted_Connection=No;')
```

However I cannot connect without user name and password:

```
import pyodbc 

conndev = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
                  'Server=server124.database.windows.net,1433;'
                  'Database=db345;'
                  'Trusted_Connection=Yes;')
```

ERROR:

```
conntest = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL 
Server]Login failed for user ''. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 
17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user ''. (18456)")
```

Comment: You may need to add an `Authentication=` keyword to your connection string. More information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/using-azure-active-directory?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: I have tried 'Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated;' and 'Authentication=ActiveDirectoryMsi;'

Getting error:
 conndev = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
pyodbc.Error: ('FA001', '[FA001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Cannot use Authentication option with Integrated Security option. (0) (SQLDriverConnect); [FA001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Cannot use Authentication option with Integrated Security option. (0)')

Comment: Problem solved by: 'Server=server124.database.windows.net,1433;'Trusted_Connection=Yes;'
 
                  '